# Vim backslash in command

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I feel like this is a very stupid question, but I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I'm relatively new to vim. After a fresh install I installed the vim-LaTeX plugin, or the LaTeX-suite for vim. It works correctly apart for the fact that there are some commands I don't understand. It gives the following instruction:

> To do this, visually select a portion of the text and press \ll while in visual mode. The visually selected portion will be saved to a temporary file with the preamble from the current document prepended. Latex-Suite will then switch focus to this temporary file and compile it

But if I press '\' it does nothing and double l moves the cursor to the right. I don't understand  what I'm supposed to be doing, and I feel incredibly stupid. Sorry if off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\` is the default value for the [`:help <Leader>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#<Leader>) key. Plugins are encouraged to start all default mappings with `<Leader>`. If you've redefined it, you need to use that key instead.

Otherwise, you need to press <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> (without <kbd>Shift</kbd>) in quick succession (by default within one second).

If you want to find out whether the plugin has been successfully installed and there's actually an action behind those keys, you can use either:

```
:verbose vmap <Leader>ll
:verbose vmap \ll
```

If Vim says `No mapping found`, or just lists other mappings starting with some of the keys, the plugin isn't installed properly, or you're not using it right.

Comment: Thanks! This was what I needed. For a quicker setup of vim I used snippets for my vimrc and accidentally also copied the line where it mapped the leader to a different key.

Comment: Ah, great! It's dangerous to copy vimrc fragments found somewhere without fully understanding them, but this is something that most of us have to learn the hard way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Press `v` to go into visual mode. Then you can use your arrow keys to select text. After you've selected the text you want, type `\ll`.

That should be it.

Comment: Okay, then I must have installed it wrong. It doesn't work for me.

Thanks for the answer though. I began losing my mind over this.

Comment: @Lightningstorms I don't actually use that plugin (I used a similar one, though) for LaTeX. I just explained to you what the quoted text actually meant, i.e. what exact steps do you need to perform, so don't take my answer as definite. But... I guess that you installed that plugin manually, right? You should use some plugin manager like [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim). Your LaTeX plugin also has a [GitHub page](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex), so with Vundle installation should be easy. Instruction are [here](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start).